# Hbase On TomCat - Class not found error

Tags: java, tomcat, hbase

I'm trying to connect to HBASE using tomcat and encountered the following error. When I run the Hbase standlone its working fine.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/Filter
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2348)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1779)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
at 
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
```

Below is the xml configuration path

```
  <configuration>
   <property>
     <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
     <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
     <description>The directory shared by region servers.
     </description>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>1</value>
      <description>The replication count for HLog and HFile storage.
      </description>              
   </property>
  </configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception clearly says that class `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.Filter` is not found in the classpath. Please add `hbase-X.X.X.jar` to the class path of the application in tomcat. Please ensure that you use the correct version of hbase jar file.

Comment: I added the tools4j-config-provider-hbase-filter-0.15-0.jar and its still generating the error

Comment: This jar doesn't contain the class 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.Filter'. it just contains these packages - 
org.deephacks.tools4j.config.internal.core.hbase
org.deephacks.tools4j.config.internal.core.hbase.query

Comment: Add the .jar file which contains the required package and class. i.e hbase-x.x.x.jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the hbase-*.jar inside tomcat's lib directory and try a re-run.